# Getting connection_abandoned_by_reqqueue error when hitting a WCF service in one environment

Tags: wcf, http

I have a WCF service deployed across three different environments. In one environment it is working fine without any issues but in other two environments it is failing to get response data. All other WCF services are working fine in those enovironments. Suddenly service started working for some time in all environments and again started same issue.
I can see error `connection_abandoned_by_reqqueue` in http logs for that particular service.
Any help would be appreciated!!